# Yield return for a public method an anti-pattern?

Tags: c#, performance, yield, yield-return

The yield return is a really nice syntax to quickly write filters or mappings that are a bit too much for shoehorning into a Linq statement. That's why I often wrote methods like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetFilteredPersons()
{
    foreach ( var person in _Persons )
    {
        // [Semi-expensive logic]
        yield return person;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the user of this method doesn't know that when he is iterating multiple times over `obj.GetFilteredPersons()` he is wasting unnecessary CPU. It could even mean when he is thinking he's is doing twice a simple `O(n)` iteration, he is in fact making twice an `O(n^2)` iteration.

**Question**

Is it the responsibility for the class to expose only `O(n)` enumerators, and am I expected to always call ToList() before returning a 'yielded' `IEnumerable`?
With the (small) disadvantage of calling an unnessary `ToList()` when the user only wants to iterate once?

Or should I leave this decission to the user of this class, and leave them to decide if they want to `ToList` the result before iterating?

*Assume we are talking about a high performance environment.*

Comment: Calling `ToList()` will only iterate once, as the enumeration will not be materialized until it's accessed.

Comment: Just my thoughts, but I would say it's the responsibility of the method consumer to call `.ToList()` if they're going to iterate the results multiple times. They shouldn't assume that they even _can_ iterate multiple times.

Comment: The code that you've shown looks like it's iterating just for the site effects.  You're not computing the values that you're generating, you're doing some other work and then returning a value you already had.  That's code smell.

Comment: Iterating a method like this twice is O(2 * n) (which is equal to O(n) ) not O(n ^2).

Comment: @Servy It sounds like OP is saying that `[semi-expensive logic]` is comparable an O(n) operation.

Comment: @JLRishe Then the operation is O(n ^ 2) even when being iterated just once, so multiple enumeration isn't an issue.

Comment: @Servy OP's concern is that performing the same O(n^2) operation twice is worse than doing it once. Whether that's a valid concern is another matter.

Comment: @Servey, I didn't want to point to specifics. It's about a case where iterating over the `IEnumerable` twice is more expensive than calling ToList() and then iterate twice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The user is responsible to calling `ToList()` on value returned from method declared as returning `IEnumerable<T>` if it known it will need multiple enumerations over returned collection and doesn't want to re-compute the values.

There is even a warning that ReSharper shows in those cases.

Also, pushing the decision down to the caller gives more flexibility, because in some cases you're not constrained on CPU, but you're constrained on memory usage, and you're OK with doing extra calculations to prevent additional allocations from happening.

Comment: One of my favorite ReSharper warnings.

Comment: Great answer! Just wondering: what about if the class already has a caching system itself? How will the user know it doesn't call `ToList()` unnecessary for a second time?

Comment: They won't. Unless they have a source code or XML comment on the method says that.

Comment: `ToList()` on an `IEnumerable` that is already a `List` is a very cheap operation. On the other hand, multiple enumerations of an `IEnumerable` can be very expensive. So don't worry about `ToList()` being a duplicate. In any case, if the callee is just doing `ToList()` before returning, then `IEnumerable` may be a poor return type. Consider `ICollection` or `IReadOnlyCollection` as a better return type that indicates to the consumer that the list is already materialized.